# Equivalent docker run command of a docker-compose file

Tags: docker, docker-compose

I am working on a project with a docker-compose.yml file having lots of interdependencies:

```
version: '3'

services:
  accounts:
    build:
      context: ./accounts
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    restart: on-failure
    depends_on:
      - ganache
    volumes:
      - ./accounts/src:/app/src
      - ./accounts/config:/app/config
      - ./accounts/.babelrc:/app/.babelrc
    environment:
      VIRTUAL_HOST: accounts.nightfall.docker

  api-gateway:
    build:
      context: ./API-Gateway
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    restart: on-failure
    volumes:
      - ./api-gateway/src:/app/src
      - ./api-gateway/.babelrc:/app/.babelrc
    environment:
      VIRTUAL_HOST: api.nightfall.docker

  ...

volumes:
  mongo-volume:
    driver: local
    driver_opts:
      type: none
      device: $PWD/../local/mongo-volume
      o: bind
  zkp-keys:
    driver: local
    driver_opts:
      type: none
      device: $PWD/../local/zkp-keys
      o: bind
```

My understanding is that Docker Compose works by running each service with parameterization for naming the services, connecting the ports and connecting the top-level volumes as specified in the Docker Compose configuration.

I suppose there would be equivalent commands for each Docker service and that is how Compose works.

How do I find, or make, these equivalent commands so I can spin up these services on my own, one-by-one, getting the identical result with Docker Compose?

Comment: What exactly are you trying to accomplish? Why not simply use `docker-compose`? What documentation have you read, and which particular parts of this compose file are you not sure how to replicate using the Docker cli tools?

Comment: I have tried `docker-compose up`, this takes an enormous amount of time building services that I don't care about. My goal is to understand one specific service so that I can document it and be sure it is working before evaluating the system as a whole.

Comment: If you don't care about the services, just remove them from the `docker-compose.yml` file? Also, it's still not clear which parts of this compose file you're unclear about. At the moment, this question reads "explain to me how docker-compose works", which is a little broad. You'll get better answers if you can narrow it down to a specific technical question.

Comment: I want to do precisely what this question asks. The reason was to get a command to run in isolation and avoid errors when doing so. I think the question is pretty focused as it currently stands and suspect "I can't answer the question, so let me solve a more general problem" tendency of SO.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, Let me try to get you out. There are 2 services here. `accounts` and `api-gateway`.

Let us try to make equivalent docker command for `accounts`.

```
  accounts:
    build:
      context: ./accounts
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    restart: on-failure
    depends_on:
      - ganache
    volumes:
      - ./accounts/src:/app/src
      - ./accounts/config:/app/config
      - ./accounts/.babelrc:/app/.babelrc
    environment:
      VIRTUAL_HOST: accounts.nightfall.docker
```

It has a build step, so we need to build the image first. `cd` to `accounts` directory and run `docker build -t myrepo/accounts:latest .`

This will build an image with name `myrepo:accounts`. Now we have to run the image. We have following properties

```
    restart: on-failure
    depends_on:
      - ganache
    volumes:
      - ./accounts/src:/app/src
      - ./accounts/config:/app/config
      - ./accounts/.babelrc:/app/.babelrc
    environment:
      VIRTUAL_HOST: accounts.nightfall.docker
```

docker command with above properties is

```
docker run myrepo:accounts --restart on-failure \
   -v "./accounts/src:/app/src" \
   -v "./accounts/config:/app/config" \
   -v "./accounts/.babelrc:/app/.babelrc" \
   -e "VIRTUAL_HOST=accounts.nightfall.docker"
```

Here, `-v` maps volumes and `-e` maps environment variables.

The next service `api-gateway` is kind of same as above.

Comment: Super helpful, thank you, this is exactly what I was looking for.

Answer (score 1):

One way you could figure this out is to use the `--verbose` flag. This will show all of the SDK commands with parameters that Docker Compose is calling and you can probably work out the equivalent Docker command from that.

```
docker-compose --verbose up -d
```